# Дубликаты продуктов в play console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, playmarket

Появилась задача, сделать аналог имеющихся подписок в google play (те же ценники, только id (sku) продуктов другой), для модификации на биллинге.
Подскажите, возможно ли дублировать имеющиеся продукты, чтобы не создавать новые?